# How to put a picture below navigationController?

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I want to build an iPhone app for my band. 
I wondered how to put a picture below the navigationController, which is visible only on pulling down (let's have a glance to this app) : 
http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/227613image.jpg

Thank a lot.

Comment: Put the photo and the table inside of a `UIScrollView`, and then set the `contentOffset` of the `UIScrollView` so that it starts out with the table positioned at the top by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use scrollview method

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{  
    CGPoint offset = scrollView.contentOffset;
    CGRect bounds = scrollView.bounds;
    CGSize size = scrollView.contentSize;
    UIEdgeInsets inset = scrollView.contentInset;
    float y = offset.y + bounds.size.height - inset.bottom;
    float h = size.height;

    if(scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0.0f && scrollView.contentOffset.y > -80.0f) 
    {
       //
        display your image at this point
        NSLog(@"\n pos: %f of %f", y, h);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it much easier:

UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,1000)];
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];

This will add a scrollView :)
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,HEIGHTYOUWANT)];
imgView.image = [UIImage imageName:@"band.png"];
[scrollView addSubview:imgView];

This will add a picture of your Band, which has to be in your Projectfolder at the top of the scrollView, so if you scroll down, the picture goes with it :)

CREATE A UINAVIGATIONBAR HERE

[self.view addSubview:navigationBar];

//^ it has to be self.view not scrollView otherwise the navigationbar moves too